# What is the difference between Julia and Julia Pro?

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

What is the difference between Julia and Julia Pro offered by Julia Computing?

Does Julia Pro have any enterprise library which isn't available in Julia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read in the [project description](https://juliacomputing.com/products/juliapro) there are a few optional packages you can install on top of the "free version" (mostly in the area of Excel integration and business workflow), but the main "difference" is in the installation process, expecially in Windows or Mac:

With standard Julia you need three steps: install Julia itself, install an editor (e.g. Juno/Atom or VScode with the Julia extension), add the desired packages.

With JuliaPro, you have these three steps by just clicking an installer.

Answer (score 1):

Julia Pro is a all in one simple solution as Anaconda for Python.